# Library not loaded: libdb2.dylib image not found

Tags: python-3.x, macos, db2, db2-400

I am trying to get the ibm_db import to work in python for some time now.

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ibm_db.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: libdb2.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ibm_db.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Does anyone have experience on mac with the ibm_db library that could help me?

Comment: Please check https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb/issues

Comment: This command resolve problem for me, try it out.
install_name_tool -change libdb2.dylib @loader_path/clidriver/lib/libdb2.dylib ibm_db.cpython-38-darwin.so
please specify your version properly in the command